# How to recreate a destroyed frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to know if it is possible to repack a frame which I destroyed earlier in python tkinter.

Is this even possible? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why can't you just, you know, _not_ destroy it? That seems like the easiest solution, no?

Comment: If it's destroyed, it's gone. If you don't want it destroyed, don't destroy it.

Comment: If the laws of physics apply to the laws of information, data can neither be created nor destroyed, so I understand the intent of the question--albeit a bit existential.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to merely hide the widget?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086482/how-to-show-hide-widgets-in-tkinter for the Nae suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to re-create or re-use a destroyed widget.

From [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method):

> **destroy()**
>
> Destroys the widget. The widget is removed from the screen, and all resources associated with the widget are released.

The important part here is that *all associated resources are released*. This includes child widgets (if the widget has any), style information (like the color, if you've explicitly set one), and pretty much everything else. All information about the widget is *gone*. Trying to access a destroyed widget will give you a Tcl error like this:

```
>>> widget.winfo_parent()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1014, in winfo_parent
    return self.tk.call('winfo', 'parent', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"
```

Once a widget is destroyed, it can't be restored. And really, there is no reason why that would be necessary. If you're planning to use a widget, don't destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't _un_destroy a widget(a frame is a widget). A possible workaround would be to *hide* & *unhide* it. You can:

```
widget.pack_forget() # hide
...
widget.pack(...) # display the widget as usual
```

If `grid` was used instead, it's even better as you can unhide, or rather redisplay, the widget exactly in the same node as before using `grid_remove`:

```
widget.grid_remove() # hide
...
widget.grid() # unhide, places the widget on the last configured node
```