# How to show and hide tkinter entry box when select yes from drop down

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

i have created an entry form for personal use using tkinter. Now i want to add a function in it that when yes if select from drop down show entry box otherwise hide it.

i have written the codes but it is not working neither 
throwing the error below is the snippet of my code

```
field = ["YES",""]
query_text = StringVar()
lblname = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Query/Reply", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname28 = OptionMenu(f1aa, query_text, *field)
txtname28.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

hidden = False
hidden_text = StringVar()
e = Entry(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = hidden_text)
e.grid(row=0, column=2)

if query_text == "YES":
    e.grid()
else:
    e.grid_remove()
#hidden = not hidden
```

full codes

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from tkinter import messagebox
import Backend
import csv
import sqlite3
import re

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
root.title("OTRS Management System")
root.configure(background="gray28")

Tops = Frame(root, width=1350, height=100,bd=14, relief="raise")
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
f1.pack(side=LEFT)

f2 = Frame(root, width=440, height=650,bd=8, relief="raise")
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

ft2 = Frame(f2, width=440, height=450,bd=12, relief="raise")
ft2.pack(side=TOP)
fb2 = Frame(f2, width=440, height=250,bd=16, relief="raise")
fb2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

f1a = Frame(f1, width=900, height=330,bd=8, relief="raise")
f1a.pack(side=TOP)
f2a = Frame(f1, width=900, height=320,bd=6, relief="raise")
f2a.pack(side=BOTTOM)

f1aa = Frame(f1a, width=400, height=330,bd=16, relief="raise")
f1aa.pack(side=LEFT)
f1ab = Frame(f1a, width=400, height=330,bd=16, relief="raise")
f1ab.pack(side=RIGHT)

f2aa = Frame(f2a, width=450, height=330,bd=14, relief="raise")
f2aa.pack(side=LEFT)
f2ab = Frame(f2a, width=450, height=330,bd=14, relief="raise")
f2ab.pack(side=LEFT)

Tops.configure(background="LightGoldenrod4")
f1.configure(background="LightGoldenrod4")
f2.configure(background="LightGoldenrod4")

field = ["YES",""]

def view_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in Backend.view():
        list1.insert(END,row)

def add_command():
    count_total_selected = [query_text.get(),
                            phase_and_tower.get(), saleable_mapping.get(), floor_plans.get(), options.get(), images.get(),
                            cons.get(), video.get(), date.get(), amenities.get(), bank.get(), latlong.get(), usp.get(),
                            facttable.get(), prj_name.get(), prj_desp.get(), specification.get(), builder.get(), tco.get(),
                            brochure.get(), prj_deactivation.get(), np.get(), np2.get(), np_refresh.get()]
    count = 0
    for i in count_total_selected:
        if i=="YES":
            count+=1
    print(count)

    if str(ticket_text.get()).isdigit()== False or len(str(ticket_text.get())) < 4  or ticket_text.get()=="" or agent_text.get()=="" or queue_text.get()=="" or inventory.get()=="":
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        label1 = Label(toplevel, text="***If you are receiving this it means you have forgotten the below points: \n Ticket number is not entered \n Queue is not selected \n Agent Name is not selected.\n Please note if XID number is not available write NA in the BOX\n Please make sure XID number starts with r or c.", height=10, width=55)
        label1.pack()
    else:
        Backend.insert(fdate, ticket_text.get(),agent_text.get(), query_text.get(), queue_text.get(), phase_and_tower.get(),saleable_mapping.get(),floor_plans.get(),options.get(), images.get(),cons.get(), video.get(),date.get(),amenities.get(),bank.get(),latlong.get(), usp.get(), facttable.get(),prj_name.get(),prj_desp.get(),specification.get(),builder.get(),tco.get(),brochure.get(),prj_deactivation.get(),np.get(),np2.get(), inventory.get(), np_refresh.get(), count)
        list1.delete(0,END)
        list1.insert(END,(fdate, ticket_text.get(),agent_text.get(), query_text.get(), queue_text.get(), phase_and_tower.get(),saleable_mapping.get(),floor_plans.get(),options.get(), images.get(),cons.get(), video.get(),date.get(),amenities.get(),bank.get(),latlong.get(), usp.get(), facttable.get(),prj_name.get(),prj_desp.get(),specification.get(),builder.get(),tco.get(),brochure.get(),prj_deactivation.get(),np.get(),np2.get(), inventory.get(), np_refresh.get(), count))

def reset():
    phase_and_tower.set("")
    saleable_mapping.set("")
    floor_plans.set("")
    options.set("")
    images.set("")
    video.set("")
    date.set("")
    amenities.set("")
    prj_deactivation.set("")
    inventory.set("")
    np2.set("")
    bank.set("")
    latlong.set("")
    usp.set("")
    facttable.set("")
    prj_name.set("")
    prj_desp.set("")
    specification.set("")
    builder.set("")
    tco.set("")
    np.set("")
    cons.set("")
    brochure.set("")
    agent_text.set("")
    queue_text.set("")
    np_refresh.set("")
    query_text.set("")
    ticket_text.set("")
def download():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("OtrsSummary.db")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    data = curs.execute("select * from otrs")
    m_dict = list(data.fetchall())
    print(m_dict)

    filename = "Productivity.csv"
    with open("./"+filename,'w') as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, m_dict)
    #csvfile.writerow(titleRow)
        csvfile.writerow(["id","Date","TicketNumber","Agent","QueryReply","Queue","PhasesandTowers","SaleableMapping","Floorplan","Options","Images","ConstructionImages","video","PossessionDate","Amenities","Bank","Location","USP","FactTable","ProjectName","Description","Specificaton","Builder","TCO","Brochure","ProjectDeactivation","NPDeactivation","NewBooking","XID Number","np_refresh","Total"])
        for i in range(0, len( m_dict )):
        #print(alldata1[i])
            csvfile.writerow( m_dict[i]  )

localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
fdate = date.today()
lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=("arial", 30, "bold"), text="OTRS Management System", fg="SteelBlue4", bd=10)
lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)
lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=("arial", 30, "bold"), text=localtime, fg="IndianRed1",bd=10)
lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=1)
#===============================All Functions===================
#===========================#first part=======================
phase_and_tower = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Phases and Tower", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname1 = OptionMenu(f1aa, phase_and_tower, *field)
txtname1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)


saleable_mapping = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Saleable Mapping", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname2 = OptionMenu(f1aa, saleable_mapping, *field)
txtname2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

floor_plans = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Floor Plan", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname3 = OptionMenu(f1aa, floor_plans, *field)
txtname3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

options = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Options", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname4 = OptionMenu(f1aa, options, *field)
txtname4.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

images = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Images", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname5 = OptionMenu(f1aa, images, *field)
txtname5.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)


video = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Video", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname6 = OptionMenu(f1aa, video, *field)
txtname6.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

##rera = StringVar()
##lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Rera", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname2.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
##txtname7 = Entry(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable=rera)
##txtname7.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)

date = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Possession Status/Date", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname8 = OptionMenu(f1aa, date, *field)
txtname8.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)

amenities = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Amenities", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname9 = OptionMenu(f1aa, amenities, *field)
txtname9.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)

prj_deactivation = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Project Deactivation", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname10 = OptionMenu(f1aa, prj_deactivation, *field)
txtname10.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)

inventory = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="XID Number", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
txtname11 = Entry(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable=inventory)
txtname11.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

np2 = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="New Booking/Resale Lock", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname12 = OptionMenu(f1aa, np2, *field)
txtname12.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)


query_text = StringVar()
lblname = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Query/Reply", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname28 = OptionMenu(f1aa, query_text, *field)
txtname28.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

hidden = False
hidden_text = StringVar()
e = Entry(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = hidden_text)
e.grid(row=0, column=2)

if query_text == "YES":
    e.grid()
else:
    e.grid_remove()
#hidden = not hidden


#######################################part2=====================
bank = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Bank", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname13 = OptionMenu(f1ab, bank, *field)
txtname13.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

latlong = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Lat Long/Location", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname14 = OptionMenu(f1ab, latlong, *field)
txtname14.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

usp = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="USP", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname15 = OptionMenu(f1ab, usp, *field)
txtname15.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

facttable = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Fact Table", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname16 = OptionMenu(f1ab, facttable, *field)
txtname16.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

prj_name = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Project Name", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname17 = OptionMenu(f1ab, prj_name, *field)
txtname17.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)

prj_desp = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Project Description", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname18 = OptionMenu(f1ab, prj_desp, *field)
txtname18.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

specification = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Project Specification", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname19 = OptionMenu(f1ab, specification, *field)
txtname19.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)

builder = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Builer Details", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname20 = OptionMenu(f1ab, builder, *field)
txtname20.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)

tco = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="TCO/Payment Plan", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname21 = OptionMenu(f1ab, tco, *field)
txtname21.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)

np = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="NP Deactivation", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname22 = OptionMenu(f1ab, np, *field)
txtname22.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)

cons = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Construction Images", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname23 = OptionMenu(f1ab, cons, *field)
txtname23.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)

brochure = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f1ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Brochure", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname24 = OptionMenu(f1ab, brochure, *field)
txtname24.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)


###======EntryWidget for checkboxes=======
#==================for Reset======================
list1=Listbox(ft2, height=22,width=59)
list1.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)

sb1=Scrollbar(ft2)
sb1.grid(row=2,column=2,rowspan=6)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')

lblreceipt = Label(ft2, font=("arial", 12, "bold"), text="View Data", bd=2, anchor="w")
lblreceipt.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

##txtReceipt = Text(ft2, width=59, height=22, bg="white", bd=8, font=("arial", 11, "bold"))
##txtReceipt.grid(row=2, column=0)

##########buttons########################
btnReset = Button(fb2, padx=16,pady=1,bd=4, fg="black", font=("arial", 8, "bold"),width=5,
                   text="Reset", command=reset).grid(row=0, column=1)
btnSubmit = Button(fb2, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black", font=("arial", 8, "bold"),width=5,
                   text="Submit", command=add_command).grid(row=0, column=2)
btnExit = Button(fb2, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black", font=("arial", 8, "bold"),width=5,
                   text="Exit", command=root.destroy).grid(row=0, column=4)

btnview = Button(fb2, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black", font=("arial", 8, "bold"),width=5,
                   text="View Data", command=view_command).grid(row=0, column=3)

download = Button(fb2, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black", font=("arial", 8, "bold"),width=5,
                   text="Download Data", command=download).grid(row=1, column=1)

########################################################################################
ticket_text = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f2aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Ticket Number", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname25 = Entry(f2aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable=ticket_text)
txtname25.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

##xid_text = StringVar()
##lblname3 = Label(f2aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="XID/TID", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
##txtname26 = Entry(f2aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = xid_text)
##txtname26.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
agents = ["Himani",
"Jhanvi",
"Sandhya",
"Juhi",
"Ruchika",
"Saurabh",
"Neha R",
"Shubhangi",
"Alisha",
"Priya S",
"Khushbu",
"Gaurav",
"Manisha",
"Anjali S",
"Sneha",
"Priyadeep",
"Anjali B",
"Rashi",
"Palak",
"Shivangi",
"Khyati",
"Alok",
"Vikas",
"Tariq",
"Vinay",
"Nupur",
"Mansi"]

agent_text = StringVar()
lblname4 = Label(f2aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Agents Name", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname27 = OptionMenu(f2aa, agent_text, *agents)
txtname27.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

field1 = ["UPGRADES", "CREATION", "MODIFICATION"]
queue_text = StringVar()
lblname2 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Queue", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
txtname29 = OptionMenu(f2ab, queue_text, *field1)
txtname29.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

np_refresh = StringVar()
lblname31 = Label(f1aa, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="NP Slot changes/Refresh", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname31.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname31 = OptionMenu(f1aa, np_refresh, *field)
txtname31.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)


##sales_text = StringVar()
##lblname3 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Sales Name", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
##txtname30 = Entry(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = sales_text)
##txtname30.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

##slot = StringVar()
##lblname2 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial",10,"bold"), text="NP Slot", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
##txtname31 = Entry(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable=slot)
##txtname31.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)


##city = StringVar()
##lblname5 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Main City", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname5.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
##txtname32 = Entry(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = city)
##txtname32.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W)

##comments = StringVar()
##lblname6 = Label(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Comments", bd=8, anchor="w")
##lblname6.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)
##txtname33 = Entry(f2ab, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = comments)
##txtname33.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=W)
##############====connecting db with fromntend====


root.mainloop()
```

I have added full codes

Comment: How exactly is it now working? Be specific

Comment: I am selecting "YES" from drop-down and nothing happened, entry box neither appeared nor hidden , no error. Like I had never added this into my code

Comment: Wait, it doesn't appear but it's not hidden? I'm confused...

Comment: I think I see the problem regardless. Your if statement there is only going to be executed once. That's not what you want. You have a tk.mainloop() called somewhere, yes?

Comment: what i am trying to do is ..if i select yes a entry box should appear.  i tried to create above codes and when ran them nothing is happening, entry box is not appearing (visible)

Comment: yes at the bottom of the code , I have defined root  = Tk() and the bottom i wrote root.mainloop()

Comment: i have added full codes also. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the logic to show or hide the Entry box is executed every time the OptionMenu selection is changed. You can do this by putting it in a function and using the OptionMenu's `command` parameter:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def hide(choice):
    if choice == "YES":
        e.grid()
    else:
        e.grid_remove()

field = ["YES",""]
query_text = StringVar()
lblname = Label(root, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Query/Reply", bd=8, anchor="w")
lblname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
txtname28 = OptionMenu(root, query_text, *field, command=hide)
txtname28.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

hidden_text = StringVar()
hidden_text.set('Show this text?')
e = Entry(root, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8, justify="left", textvariable = hidden_text)
e.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i had no idea about option menu command parameter. That's nice. Thank you so much for your help. It's a great learning indeed

Comment: To be fair, it isn't the best documented feature. However, if you look at the source code of `tkinter.OptionMenu` it has a comment in `def __init__(self, master, variable, value, *values, **kwargs)` stating: `Construct an optionmenu widget with the parent MASTER, with the resource textvariable set to VARIABLE, the initially selected value VALUE, the other menu values VALUES and an additional keyword argument command.`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is replace your `root.mainloop()` with a custom loop you made yourself that incorporated your if statement in it. As you have it right now, that is statement is only going to be called once, and that's before you GUI even becomes operational. Instead of checking to see if the value has changed just once at the beginning, to need to make it keep checking all the time.

Checking when things are happening all the time is what `root.mainloop()` does, but what you need is beyond what `root.mainloop()` does. So what you need is a loop you made yourself (as I was saying above) that can check when the value has changed and update the GUI accordingly.

In your loop, you'll need to also make sure that your GUI is still responding manually. This is usually done by `root.mainloop()`, but since you need to replace it, you need to do it yourself. There are a bunch of ways to do this, but start off by looking into `root.update()` and putting that in your own loop.

EDIT: Actually, have you considered using a check box instead of a drop down menu? You can attack a function to it and make it show or hide the widget when you press it. Also you should consider enabling and disabling the widget rather than hiding or showing it. This will mean less problem with the layout

Comment: Doesn't matter. Read the answer I have given here

Comment: but my whole GUI is actually designed like drop down and since i am actually new to tkinter, i didn't know how to connect check boxes with sqlite3, so yes i have less idea, i thought it will look cool

Comment: I read the article here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086482/how-to-show-hide-widgets-in-tkinter?rq=1
and learnt from this