# Tkinter first click first function, second click second function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working with tkinter for a while. I try to make an application based on the code here: 
[How to show/hide widgets in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086482/how-to-show-hide-widgets-in-tkinter)

i have two function toggle_entry and comp_s. 
How can I run toggle_entry+comp_s when I first click the button? and when I click a second time how do I run toggle_entry.When I click for the third time, again toggle_entry + comp_s, when I click for the fourth time, again toggle_entry etc. ...

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk

hidden = False
root = tk.Tk()
r = StringVar() 
e = tk.Entry(root, width=6, textvariable=r)
e.grid(row=0, column=1)

def toggle_entry():
    global hidden
    if hidden:
        e.grid()
    else:
        e.grid_remove()
    hidden = not hidden

s = StringVar() 
def comp_s(event):
    global s
    s=r.get() # construct string
    print(s)

tk.Button(root, text='Toggle entry', command=toggle_entry).grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can make some thing like this

```
count = 0
def test_click():
   global count
   count +=1
   if count%2 ==0:
       toggle_entry()
       comp_s(event)
   else :
        toggle_entry()
tk.Button(root, text='Toggle entry', command=test_click).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alicoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "a.py", line 30, in test_click
    comp_s(event)
NameError: name 'event' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add a "num_clicked" attribute to the button upon its declaration. Then, every time it's callback is executed, you check that and act accordingly:

```
def toggle_entry():
    # First thing is to increment the number of clicks
    button.num_clicked += 1

    # Your codes
    ...

    # At the end, call comp_s depending on the number of clicks
    if num_clicked % 2:
        comp_s(None)

...
# Initialization of the button
button = tk.Button(root, text='Toggle entry', command=toggle_entry)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
button.num_clicked = 0
```

`if num_clicked % 2` implies "run this block only if `num_clicked` is odd (e.g. 1st click, 3rd click)". Also, we pass `None` to `comp_s` as it expects an argument, but it is okay to pass anything because it is not used in the function anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
count = 1
def test_click():
   global count
   count +=1
   if count%2 ==0:
    comp_s()
    toggle_entry()

   else :
        toggle_entry()
tk.Button(root, text='Toggle entry', command=test_click).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

i will add this line under the comp_s function it worked.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. This answer would be better if you included an explanation of your changes. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what changed.